# Why do I get a leak when using CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsmutabledictionary

I am creating a deep mutable copy of a dictionary but for some reason am getting a leak. I've tried this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableCopy = (NSMutableDictionary *)CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, sectionedDictionaryByFirstLetter, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers);
self.copyOfSectionedDictionaryByFirstLetter = mutableCopy;
CFRelease(mutableCopy);
```

And this:

```
copyOfSectionedDictionaryByFirstLetter = (NSMutableDictionary *)CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, sectionedDictionaryByFirstLetter, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers);
```

Both are being flagged by interface builder's leaks device.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Does doing a build and analyze find anything?

Comment: No... unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you are retaining one of the objects in the dictionary.  What is the number of leaked bytes?

Comment: That seems to have been it. I'm going to continue debugging for a couple of days to make sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually release `copyOfSectionedDictionaryByFirstLetter` in your `dealloc` method?

You will either have to do:

```
self.copyOfSectionedDictionaryByFirstLetter = nil;
```

Or:

```
[copyOfSectionedDictionaryByFirstLetter release];
copyOfSectionedDictionaryByFirstLetter = nil; // Just for good style
```

Comment: Yes, I do release it. The leak shows up whenever a method is called in my appDelegate that runs the code in my question above. I'm really scratching my head over this one.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the immediate case to `NSMutableDictionary` is confusing the profiler. Try the following:

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef mutableCopy = CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, sectionedDictionaryByFirstLetter, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers);
if (mutableCopy) {
    // NOTE: you MUST check that CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy() did not return NULL.
    // It can return NULL at any time, and then passing that NULL to CFRelease() will crash your app.
    self.copyOfSectionedDictionaryByFirstLetter = (NSMutableDictionary *)mutableCopy;
    CFRelease(mutableCopy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling part below multiple times:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableCopy = (NSMutableDictionary *)CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, sectionedDictionaryByFirstLetter, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers);
self.copyOfSectionedDictionaryByFirstLetter = mutableCopy;
CFRelease(mutableCopy);
```

you should change it to:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableCopy = (NSMutableDictionary *)CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, sectionedDictionaryByFirstLetter, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers);
[self.copyOfSectionedDictionaryByFirstLetter release];
self.copyOfSectionedDictionaryByFirstLetter = mutableCopy;
CFRelease(mutableCopy);
```

I guess that can be your reason for the leak.